# Is sudo chown safe to use on a file I am not the owner of?

Tags: python, terminal, permissions, chown

I am simply trying to pip install beautifulsoup4 but upon doing so i get this error:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.6.0.dist-info'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

so I did this to check who 'owns' the file although this is my personal laptop with:

```
ls -l /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages and it returned this:
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  157 Oct  7  2017 Extras.pth
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  119 Oct  7  2017 README
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  218 Jul 15 20:20 easy-install.pth
drwxr-xr-x  4 root  wheel  128 Jul 15 20:20 pip-10.0.1-py2.7.egg
```

so I tried to change ownership to user to thiss directory only with the following:

```
chown gaby:staff /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

and this was returned:

```
chown: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages: Operation not permitted
```

is it because I am the macintosh HD has a separate file for library and users meaning me, being in the users file, isn't the root who 'owns' the file? If so, does this mean I should use

```
sudo chown gaby:staff /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

??? Is that a safe thing to do and does sudo even do anything if I'm not on Unix(I am on mac os)? I'm also confused as to why I'm even having this issue if the site-packages folder is specifically for third party packages.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `sudo pip install beautifulsoup4` or, preferably, use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/). You should be able to do either of these without changing permissions on the above directories.

Comment: But it should be emphasised that on macOS, should always use a virtualenv. If have to install anything in system Python, limit it to virtualenv and pip, so can create those virtual environments. You really don't want to risk installing into system Python and screwing up the operating system bits that use the system Python.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I tried 'pip install virtualenv' and got the same errno 13 I wrote about above. is this normal???

Comment: To install initial ``virtualenv``, run ``sudo pip install virtualenv``. After that, create virtual environments, work in those, and do not use ``sudo``.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Thank you so much for your help! it worked